# Any way to stop Firefox safe mode opening up when running parallel tests?

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver

Is there any way to stop Firefox safe mode opening up when running parallel tests? I am running tests in parallel and need to be able to stop the firefox safe mode from popping up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any situation where you want to disable SafeMode, [editing the SafeMode.xul file](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/664785) is the most popular way to permanently disable Safe Mode.

**NOTE!** The method to disable safe mode is a fairly complicated technique for beginners.

In my case I needed to parallelly run tests on several Firefox windows. (Not using Selenium though). This worked for me.